# iOS profile issue

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

When I try to download my app to App Store I receive the following message **"Profile doesn't include the com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning entitlement. Provisioning profile failed qualification"**. The app has been in use ApplePay for two years now. The only change is new Xcode 15. If anyone has thoughts on this I would be grateful.

What has already been done:

1. Removing files from */Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/* and downloading them again from dev portal
2. Generating a new profile and uploading it.

Thank you.

Comment: Entitlements are increasingly configured via Xcode's Capabilities UI. Can you check those in your project?

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Wallet capability is on in Xcode. Pass Types checked mode is 'Allow all team pass types'. But the problem was not solved.

Answer (score 1):

Issue did fix. When loading ipa to AppStore, I selected the **"Custom"** download mode. So he acts like Xcode 14 upload flow & I and I was able to select certificate & profiles manually.